# Errors in laravel-5 configuration

Tags: php, laravel-5, apache2, laravel-5.3, php-7.1

I got multiple errors while configurating project on laravel (downloading existing project using git and composer). Errors are shown after logging to the main page of project, login panel is displayed properly.

(1/4) FatalThrowableError

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'const' (T_CONST), expecting
>   variable (T_VARIABLE)
>       in PDOStatement.php line 40

(2/4) PDOException

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS requires
>   format array(classname, array(ctor_args)); the classname must be a
>   string specifying an existing class
>       in PDOConnection.php line 47

(3/4) PDOException

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS requires 
>       format array(classname, array(ctor_args)); the classname must be a string specifying an existing class
>
> in PDOConnection.php line 50

(4/4) QueryException

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: PDO::ATTR_STATEMENT_CLASS requires 
>       format array(classname, array(ctor_args)); the classname must be a string specifying an existing class (SQL: select * from "users" where
>   "email" = [my_email] limit 1)
>       in Connection.php line 647

im using php7.1, postgres, apache2 server, doctrine/dbal(2.6.3)

migrate database using php artisan